# Convert an Array of Array to Array of Object

Tags: javascript

I have an array of arrays (2d array), and I want to convert it into an array of objects. In the resulting array, I would like each object to have a key-name (see expected output below)

```
data = [
 ['Apple', 'Orange', 'Banana', 'Pears', 'Peach'],
 [40, 35, 25, 58, 84],
 [2, 4, 4, 3, 1, 2],
 ['Red', 'Yellow', 'Green', 'Violet', 'Blue']
];
```

My expected result:

```
expected_result = [
  {name: 'Apple', price: 40, quantity: 2, color: 'Red'},
  {name: 'Orange', price: 35, quantity: 4, color: 'Yellow'},
  {name: 'Banana', price: 25, quantity: 4, color: 'Green'},
  {name: 'Pears', price: 58, quantity: 1, color: 'Violet'},
  {name: 'Peach', price: 84, quantity: 2, color: 'Blue'}
];
```

**Note** The iteration of each array (in `data`) should be consecutive so that it gives the expected result

Comment: Hey Arup, welcome to StackOverflow. This is a debugging site, but you haven't given us anything to debug! Please edit your question to include your code/attempt(s).

Answer (score 1):

Seems to be there is one item extra in the `quantity` values. I have updated 
`[2, 4, 4, 3, 1, 2]` to `[2, 4, 4, 1, 2]` removed `3` to match the result, hoping its a typo.

```js
let data = [
  ["Apple", "Orange", "Banana", "Pears", "Peach"],
  [40, 35, 25, 58, 84],
  [2, 4, 4, 1, 2],
  ["Red", "Yellow", "Green", "Violet", "Blue"]
];

let output = [];
let props = ["name", "price", "quantity", "color"];

function updateInfo(row, prop){
  row.filter((value, index) => {
    if (output[index]) {
      output[index][prop] = value;
    } else {
      output.push({
        [prop]: value
      });
    }
  });
};

data.filter((row, index) => {
  updateInfo(row, props[index]);
});



console.log(output);
```

Comment: oh yes.. its typo.. did you understand my question Mr. Dipak, can you pls solve it

Comment: I have added the code snippet along with my answer, please expand and check it. :)

Answer (score 1):

One solution consist of creating first a [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) between the `outter-array` indexes and the `property` (or `key`) name you want to assign to them (however this could be replaced by an array like this `["name","price","quantity","color"]`). Also, you can obtain the `minimun length` of the inner arrays to later check for non-creation of `objects` that won't have all the properties. After you do this pre-initialization, you can use [Array.reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) to generate your expected result:

```js
const data = [
 ['Apple', 'Orange', 'Banana', 'Pears', 'Peach'],
 [40, 35, 25, 58, 84],
 [2, 4, 4, 3, 1, 2],
 ['Red', 'Yellow', 'Green', 'Violet', 'Blue']
];

let mapIdxToProp = new Map([[0, "name"],[1, "price"],[2, "quantity"],[3, "color"]]);
let minLen = Math.min(...data.map(x => x.length));

let res = data.reduce((acc, arr, idx) =>
{
    arr.forEach((x, j) =>
    {
        (j < minLen) && (acc[j] = acc[j] || {}, acc[j][mapIdxToProp.get(idx)] = x);
    });
    return acc;
}, []);

console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 1):

The **simplest** (not most efficient) solution *in my opinion* is to simply loop through the array, adding to another array as you go.

```js
let arr = [
  ['Apple', 'Orange', 'Banana', 'Pears', 'Peach'],
  [40, 35, 25, 58, 84],
  [2, 4, 4, 1, 2],
  ['Red', 'Yellow', 'Green', 'Violet', 'Blue']
];
let keys = ["name", "price", "quantity", "color"];
let output = [];

//Add's blank objects too the output array
for (let i = 0; i < arr[0].length; i++) {
  output.push({});
}

//Loops through the array
for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  //Loops through the sub array
  for (let x = 0; x < arr[i].length; x++) {
    //Adds the sub array to the key that corresponds to it
    output[x][keys[i]] = arr[i][x];
  }
}

console.log(output);
```